# Cumulative Count of Members by Month DPLYR

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list of members by signup month, what I'd like to do is create a data frame with total members by month.

Raw Data

```
month.list <- structure(c(18444, 18687, 18475, 18506, 18536, 18567, 18597,18718, 18659, 18628, 18779, 18748), class = "Date") 
total.membership.working <- structure(list(`Mem Account` = c(26137295, 26139796, 26400007,26400455, 26402031, 26402078, 26402239, 1092287142, 1092295228,1092473120), Month = structure(c(18444, 18687, 18444, 18444,18475, 18475, 18444, 18779, 18779, 18779), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA,-10L), groups = structure(list(`Mem Account` = c(26137295, 26139796,26400007, 26400455, 26402031, 26402078, 26402239, 1092287142,1092295228, 1092473120), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of","vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df","tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have written a for loop that will accomplish this, but I'm hoping to find a Tidy way to do it without the loop.

For Loop

```
total.membership <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(month.list)) {
  
  foo <- total.membership.working %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    filter(Month <= month.list[i]) %>%
    summarise(Month = max(Month),
      total_membership = n_distinct(`Mem Account`))
  total.membership <- total.membership %>%
    bind_rows(foo)
}
```

Desired Output

```
total.membership <- structure(list(Month = structure(c(18444, 18687, 18475, 18506,18536, 18567, 18597, 18628, 18779, 18748), class = "Date"), total_membership = c(45886L,58128L, 47878L, 49214L, 51119L, 53390L, 55200L, 56299L, 60503L,59583L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 11L,12L), class = "data.frame") 

> total.membership
        Month total_membership
1  2020-07-01            45886
2  2021-03-01            58128
3  2020-08-01            47878
4  2020-09-01            49214
5  2020-10-01            51119
6  2020-11-01            53390
7  2020-12-01            55200
8  2021-04-01            58902
9  2021-02-01            57238
10 2021-01-01            56299
11 2021-06-01            60503
12 2021-05-01            59583
```

Comment: I think your input and expected are not the same.  I tried on your loop with the input and it gives different values for desired

Comment: If you want to get a new value (total membership) for every value in month.list, then lapply would be a natural fit

Comment: Are the values in your first data set correct? I just don't understand how we get from those numbers to this desired output.

Comment: I realized that using `reproduce()` gives you a sample, rather than the whole dataframe, which is kind of important in this question.  My starting data was 60,503 unique members and their sign up date, what I'm trying to get it is basically how to add each prior month to the new sign ups for the current month.

Comment: Please use `dput(head(data))` to create a reproducible data sample.

Comment: ```structure(list(`Mem Account` = c(26137295, 26139796, 26400007, 
26400455, 26402031, 26402078), Month = structure(c(18444, 18687, 
18444, 18444, 18475, 18475), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(`Mem Account` = c(26137295, 26139796, 
26400007, 26400455, 26402031, 26402078), .rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to calculate cumulative unique accounts in each month.

```
library(dplyr)

total.membership.working %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(Month) %>%
  mutate(cum_n = cumsum(!duplicated(`Mem Account`))) %>%
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  summarise(cum_unique_entries = max(cum_n))

#  Month      cum_unique_entries
#  <date>                  <int>
#1 2020-07-01                  4
#2 2020-08-01                  6
#3 2021-03-01                  7
#4 2021-06-01                 10
```